# Workflow: Send email when document is modified the first time

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, document-library, approval, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I currently have a 2010 workflow set up in SharePoint Designer where an email is triggered when a certain field is changed. For example, if the user changes the status that equals "reviewed w/ comments", it will trigger an email to the project leader. However, any time someone edits and saves the document after this point, it will continue to send the same email. How can I set up the workflow so it only triggers the email the FIRST TIME the field changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a hiden field "SendMail" in the workflow you can aks if this field is 0 then send the mail and set the field to 1. So the first time the workflow will run, it will send the Mail after that because the field is not equal 0 it won't send the mail anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new workflow, add the action "Pause for duration" in the workflow, set the number of days as large as possible. In the method, the workflow will in progress.
[image]

2.Create a new column in the library, set the default value of column as "Yes". Then design the workflow as following picture shows.
[image]